# Using images when posting RSS feed to Facebook page

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, rss, feed

I create an RSS feed and by using this feed and a third party application I post feed items into my Facebook page.

Everyting works fine except images. Every item of my feed has an image link. As far as image tags aren't allowed as RSS2 I encode HTML code and put it inside description, like this:

```
<item><title>My item</title>
<link>http://example.com/mypage1.html</link>
<description>This is very important item please read this
&amp;lt;img=&amp;quot;http://example.com/image.jpg&amp;quot;&amp;gt;</description>
</item>
```

Everything works well, but image of the post is not the same within item description tag. 
Facebook puts one of the images inside `http://example.com/mypage1.html` page.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get or build a different third party application that will include the image parameters in the post.  Or put the right open graph meta tags on your page for the image, i.e.:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yoursite.com/image.jpg" />
```

More information here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices